# WPF Data Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

when do i use each of the following?

```
{Binding ElementName=...}
{Binding Source=...}

{Binding ... Path=...}
<TextBox DisplayMemberPath=...}
// and i think i saw something like ...
{Binding xxx}
```

i also wonder if there are any other ways of data binding i need to be aware of? i am new to C#/WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data binding can be a complex and tricky subject. Take a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/WPFBindingCheatSheet11222009133459PM/WPFBindingCheatSheet.aspx) for cheat-sheet that I like to use, and [here is one in a pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can learn core abilities of WPF from this  [cheet sheet](http://blog.codebeach.com/2009/11/free-wpf-cheat-sheet.html)